# IIS Error Message

Tags: iis

I generated a new web site in IIS. Under the new web site, there are some asp .net 2.0 applications. Tomcat is also running on the same server and they are working correctly.
But when I try to open an asp .net application, I am taking page can not be found error message. Then I changed the configuration settings of asp .net version from 2.0 to 1.1 then it is not giving page can not be found message but it gives an error message about  web config. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given many details. This could be a couple of things:

- you have used an incorrect URL
- you have used an incorrect protocol (i.e. http instead of https)
- you are specifying a directory but you have no default document set up (i.e. you are going to http://mywebsite/myvirtualdir/, but you have no default.aspx)
- you haven't installed ASP.NET so there are no handlers for aspx pages

until you give more details then no-one can say for sure what your problem is.